# regex scan files for specific contents

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to read all my project files and it's contents to detect some strings.

I have a working piece of code now, but there are some missing parts.

The goal is to scan all of my files and add some items into the database if they occure in a scanned file.

For example;

I have some code like this:

`@can('event-tools::menu.view')` then it should return `event-tools::menu.view` as "found string".

I also have something like `$this->middleware('can:access registration check');`, then it should also detect the `access registration check`

I currently work with a regex to scan the file contents like this:

```
[^\w](@can|hasPermissionTo|hasDirectPermission)\(\s*(?P<quote>['"])(?P<string>(?:\\k{quote}|(?!\k{quote}).)*)\k{quote}\s*[\),]
```

Anyone who might be able to help with this? Or if I should use another approach?

I check for matches using the following:

`preg_match_all("/$stringPattern/siU", $fileContents, $matches)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) and match the 2 different formats using an alternation with the same named groups.

```
(?|(?:@can|hasPermissionTo|hasDirectPermission)\(\s*(?P<quote>['"])(?P<string>.*?)\1\)|\((?P<quote>['"])can:(?P<string>.*?)\1\)|\(\[[^][]*(?P<quote>['"])can:(?P<string>.*?)\1[^][]*]\))
```

The pattern in parts, using 2 alterations `|` for 3 different variations:

- `(?|` Branch reset group

  - `(?:@can|hasPermissionTo|hasDirectPermission)` Match 1 of the alternatives
  - `\(\s*` Match `(` and optional whitespace chars
  - `(?P<quote>['"])` Match either `'` or `"` in group *quote*
  - `(?P<string>.*?)\1` Group *string* Match as least as possible chars till the same quote that was captured in group *quote*
  - `\)` Match `)`
  - `|` Or
  - `\(` Match `(`
  - `(?P<quote>['"])` - Same as before
  - `can:` Match literally (Or use an alternation again for multiple words)
  - `(?P<string>.*?)\1` - Same as before
  - `\)` Match `)`
  - `|` Or
  - `\(\[` Match `([`
  - `[^][]*` Match any char except `[` and `]`
  - `(?P<quote>['"])` Same as before
  - `can:` Match literally
  - `(?P<string>.*?)\1` Same as before
  - `[^][]*]\)` Match any char except `[` `]` using a negated characer class,  then match `])`
- `)` Close branch reset group

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oJSyU7/1).

```
$re = '/(?|(?:@can|hasPermissionTo|hasDirectPermission)\(\s*(?P<quote>[\'"])(?P<string>.*?)\1\)|\((?P<quote>[\'"])can:(?P<string>.*?)\1\)|\(\[[^][]*(?P<quote>[\'"])can:(?P<string>.*?)\1[^][]*]\))/';
$str = <<<'STR'
@can('event-tools::menu.view')
$this->middleware('can:access registration check');
Route::prefix('administration')->middleware(['auth', 'verified', 'can:access admin area'])->group(static function () {
STR;

$result = preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches["string"]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => event-tools::menu.view
    [1] => access registration check
    [2] => access admin area
)
```

Comment: By trying to understand the code you wrote, I think this; `(?|(?:@can|hasPermissionTo|hasDirectPermission)\(\s*(?P<quote>['"])(?P<string>.*?)\1\)|\((?P<quote>['"])can:(?P<string>.*?)\1\)|(?P<quote>['"])can:(?P<string>.*?)\1)` might be the solution for that?

Comment: @Robin You could write it like that yes if you don't want a rule that if should be between the outer `([` and `])`

Comment: I think such rule would be safer to have

Comment: @Robin For that occurrence you could write it like `(?|(?:@can|hasPermissionTo|hasDirectPermission)\(\s*(?P<quote>['"])(?P<string>.*?)\1\)|\((?P<quote>['"])can:(?P<string>.*?)\1\)|\(\[[^][]*(?P<quote>['"])can:(.*?)\1[^][]*]\))` https://regex101.com/r/ZZQ70O/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/9QoVbZ/1 in here you see that when there is a parameter after that, it also see that one as a match, but that should not hapen

Comment: @Robin I updated the previous comment, it would be https://regex101.com/r/oJSyU7/1